# OmniPlan showing one task per day

Tags: gantt

I've just started using omniplan and it's somehow showing my project taskas one per day.

How do I revert this to multiple tasks per day?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by changing the "Granularity" in the project info window from 'Daily Scheduling' to 'Exact Scheduling'

[image]